# Remove scrollbar when there is no need to scroll on an html page embedded into another html page

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am coding a website in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I have an HTML page within another HTML page. This embedded page has a scroll bar even when there is no need to scroll. I want to get rid of this bar until it is actually needed.

"overflow: auto;" does not fix the problem and I cannot make the page not have a scroll bar using "overflow: hidden;" because in some zoom settings, the user does need to scroll.

**My code to embed the html page**

```
<iframe src="Flip_turn/index.html" width="100%" height="650" frameborder="0" style="border: 0"></iframe>
```

**Screenshot of website area with error:**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDlzh.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, there is a small scrollbar that sticks out just a bit on a section of the website. This is the problematic one. It allows the user to scroll just a tiny bit even when there is no need to scroll.

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks to all who give answers!

Comment: It's likely that the page is taller than 650 pixels. Increase it.

Comment: There _is_ something to scroll, otherwise the scrollbar would not appear. So you need to make the iframe higher, or the content displayed inside it shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. You were right, I just needed to increase the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scrolling to the iframe:

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

If that does not work add overflow hidden:

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```